# me dice que no se puede convertir de int a bool , alguna idea?

Tags: c#, booleano

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calc1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long num1;
            long num2;
            string funcion64;

            Console.Write("Teclee el número que desea multiplicar: ");
            funcion64 = Console.ReadLine();
            num1 = Convert.ToInt64(funcion64);
            Console.Write("Introduzca el número por el que se multiplicará: ");
            funcion64 = Console.ReadLine();
            num2 = Convert.ToInt64(funcion64);
            Console.WriteLine(num1 + " * " + num2);
            Console.Write("Aquí está el resultado: " + num1*num2 + " <ahora presione cualquier tecla para finalizar>");
            Console.Read();
            bool r;
            r = 82;
            System.ConsoleKeyInfo decision;
            decision = Console.ReadKey(r);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No puedes utilizar de int a boolean

Comment: Aquí, declaras la variable como booleana: `bool r;` y luego le asignas un entero: `r = 82;`, eso no es posible, porque `r` al ser booleana sólo acepta `true` o `false` como valor, nada más.

Comment: tendrias que colocar un condicional si es x numero sea true or false seria como colocar if( r == 82) then return else ...el resto de logica

Answer (score 4):

es que no se puede. un **booleano** solo puede tomar los valores `true` o `false`, es un absurdo querer asignarle un **entero**. no se  que querías hacer . explícate un poco mas.

Answer (score 1):

Como te explicaron la variable **boolean** solo toma valores true or false.

Lo que estas intentando hacer es utilizar la variable **intercept**: si está en ***true*** la tecla presionada es interceptada y no se muestra en la ventana por el contrario si está en ***false*** si se muestra.

Su utilización sería:

```
bool r = true; //o false
System.ConsoleKeyInfo decision;
decision = Console.ReadKey(r);

Console.Write("Presionaste ");
Console.Write(decision.KeyChar);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

yo he visto algo similar en código pero de intención distinta,

ejemplo:

```
int r = 82;
bool r2;
if (r>valor){r2 = true;}
else{r2=false;}
```

Es decir, la variable no es realmente de tipo bool sino int, lo único que se comprueba si alcanza un cierto valor. Es esta tu idea?